# PHP nested loop behaving unexpectedly

Tags: php, mysql, loops, nested-loops

I have an array which contains the categories for a particular article ($link_cat). I'm then using mysql_fetch_array to print out **all** of the categories available into a list with checkboxes. While it's doing this I want it to compare the value it's on, to a value from the other array. If there is a match, then it means that one of the categories applies to this article, and it should print out a line of code to apply the checked attribute. great! except it's not working =[

```
    while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_ASSOC) ){
    $cat[$i] = $row['category'];
    $cat_id[$i] = $row['cat_id'];

    echo '<li><input type="checkbox" ';

    $catCount = count($link_cat);
    for ($ct = 0; $ct < $catCount; $ct++){
        if ($cat_id[$i] == $link_cat[$ct]){ 
            echo 'checked="checked" ';
        }
    }

    echo 'name="' . $cat_id[$i] . '" />' . $cat[$i] . '</li>';

    $i++;
}
```

I've never really done a nested loop before (I suspect thats the problem).

The problem seems to be that when this runs, $link_cat[0] which will have the first category to check against in it - doesn't register. It comes up blank. Printing out variables inside the for loop confirmed this. Any others [1] [2] etc, are fine. It's just [0]. But why? it doesn't seem to make any sense. I know there is something in there, because I printed the contents of array as I filled it it, just to check. Yet it doesn't just show during the loop. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show the code that fills $link_cat?

Comment: Agreed, that seems more likely to be where the problem is.

Comment: Did you initialise $i to be zero before entering the while loop?

Comment: 1) Can you show what var_dump($row) shows for at least one row in the while() loop?

2) $i is somewhere uninitialized yes. could possibly be a problem.

3) for() loop is extremely ineffective. Should at the very least have a break; statement in the if() after finding matching category!

Comment: 4) also, unless you are doing it as part of some school project, I would bet it makes more sense to use some framework that handles stuff of this level automatically.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

slight bug fix (and blatant style change): Your version can print out checked="checked" multiple times. Do `$cat` and `$cat_id` need to be arrays?

```
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_ASSOC) ) {
    $cat = $row['category'];
    $cat_id = $row['cat_id'];

    echo '<li><input type="checkbox" ';
    if ( in_array($cat_id, $link_cat) ) {
        echo 'checked="checked" ';
    }
    echo "name='$cat_id' />$cat</li>";
}
```

For situation where one would normally throw a debugger at a problem, I like to throw in a nice [print_r](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) in a comment block (view-source for debug output, safer on live-ish sites).

```
echo '<!-- ' . print_r($link_cat, TRUE) . ' -->';
```

Comment: Thanks friend, much appreciated. Your way was much better, I'm learning :)

Answer (score 0):

While I was originally very wrong about the array looping needing a reset, I can't shake the feeling that looping through that array isn't the fastest way to do what you are after.

Perhaps [array_search](https://www.php.net/array_search) would do, or maybe [array_key_exists](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php).  [in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) look like a winner but I didn't think of it

Comment: He's accessing by index, reset() is unnecessary.

Comment: I get it.  I will remove the dumb part of my response.